# Launch Failed. Binary not found - C/C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

When I want to run this program it gives me the error "***launch failed etc.***". Futhermore it says that ***cout***, ***string*** and ***close*** couldn't be resolved and that it expected ";" before "*myfile*"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main () {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile ("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\cas.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
        std::myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Have tried "Build project"

Comment: Write `std::` before the stl types like string and ifstream. You can also write `using namespace std;` after your includes, but beware of name clashes.

Comment: Before each type so like the edited version?

Comment: You also want double backslashes or single forward slashes in your path string.

Comment: @BetaCarotin : it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I commented the changes. Basically, everything from the standard library has to be prefixed with `std::`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
        // prefixed with std
    std::ifstream myfile ("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\cas.txt");
        // prefixed with std, escaped backslashes
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(myfile, line))
            // prefixed with std
        {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
                // prefixed with std
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
            // prefixed with std

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @Bob What does your program output look like? Look for exceptions. Try using breakpoints and step through your code to find the problem.

Comment: It says `Nothing to build for C`

Comment: @Bob I have not worked with Eclipse before, but the code itself seems fine. Check your build settings. `Nothing to build for C` sounds to me like it tries to build C code while your code is C++. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Bob Do you mean which editor/compiler I use? If so, I use Visual Studio and Qt Creator for the stuff I do.